# How to move a JAR file from one server on CI CD Gitlab to another server after a build

Tags: java, gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops, cicd

I have a CI CD in GitLab and I have a Java Project. After  building the project, I want to send it (Jar File from artifact) to another server.

Note. Git runner is installed on the same server. (The server operating system is Windows)

```
image: maven:latest

variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s .m2/settings.xml --batch-mode"
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"

cache:
  key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
  paths:
    - .m2/repository/

stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

test:
  script:
    - mvn clean test

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn clean install
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/Practice.jar

deploy: 
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - cp target/Practice.jar "D:\OtherTest"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run a script in after_script to copy it to another location. after_script runs after a job succeeds.

```
build:
 stage: build
 script:
   - mvn clean install
 artifacts:
  paths:
   - target/Practice.jar
 after_script
   - #run some command to copy to other server
```

Another idea is to create a drive mapping on your container host to this other server, then create a volume that connects that location to your artifacts location, so when the job completes it would just be available there.

```
docker run -v g:\{location}:c:\{artifacts location}
```